# Is firewall needed for guest OS in VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I enable Firewall and AntiVirus on a VirtualPC VM?](https://superuser.com/questions/441214/should-i-enable-firewall-and-antivirus-on-a-virtualpc-vm)

I have good firewall on host OS (WinXP), Do I need additional firewall in guest OS (Fedora)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will highly depend on where your firewall is placed.

I think you will still need a firewall as most applications just bridge your physical interface with your virtual ones.

If your virtual interfaces are positioned behind the firewall than you can control in and out going to and from your guest OS with one firewall.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be necessary but that will depend if you have sensitive information that you want to kept confidential inside your VM. I highly suggest that you should take a look at protecting your network right from the router itself then dig on the software firewall to further enhance your control and monitor network traffic that goes in/out of your system.